# GuidedStepFragment is added but can't control?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

My activity already added a fragment. When I add a GuidedStepFragment into my activity :

```
ex: GuidedStepFragment.add(getFragmentManager(), new GuidedStepActivity.FirstStepFragment());
```

Although GuidedStepFragment'UI show in the front screen, but I can't control this.(still control backgroud fragment)

How can I focus on GuidedStepFragment??

Just like Youtube(android-tv version), in watch any video page,click "Flag" icon, it will show GuidedStepFragment'UI.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Is your activity doing any sort of overrides on controller inputs? If you are doing custom controller actions in `onKeyDown` or something, and then returning false, that `KeyEvent` will not continue to propagate

Comment: Thank you for your reply~~  But I don't doing any custom controller actions in onKeyDown. My activity is a clear activity, it have a fragment( that have button witch can open a GuidedStepFragment).

Comment: It is a very simple project, but i can not reach my desired effect. I think this is the limitation of GuidedStepFragment??( The limitation is "GuidedStepFragment can't add in a activity which already have a fragment" ??? ).
I do not know what I think is correct. Who can help me answer it?